# How to properly do custom markdown markup

Tags: lua, pandoc, markup

I currently work on a personal writing project which has ended up with me maintaining a few different versions due to the differences of the relevant platforms and output formats I want to support that are not trivially solved. After several instances of me glancing at pandoc and the sheer forest that it represents, I have concluded mere templates don't do what I need, and worse, that I seem to need a combination of a custom filter and writer... suffice to say: messing with the AST is where I feel way out of my depth. Enough so that, rather than asking specific questions of 'how do I do X' here, this is a question of 'is X the right way to go about it, or what is the proper way to do it, and can you give an example of how it ties together?'... so if this question is rather lengthy: my apologies.

My current goal is to have custom markup like the following which is supposed to 'track' which character says something:

```
<paul|"Hi there">
```

If I convert to HTML, I'd want something similar to:

```
<span class="speech paul">"Hi there"</span>
```

to pop out (and perhaps the <p> tags), whereas if it is just pure markdown / plain text, I'd want it to silently disappear:

```
"Hi there"
```

Looking at the JSON AST structures I've studied, it would make sense that I'd want a new structure type similar to the 'Emph' tag called 'Speech' which allows whole blobs of text to be put inside of it with a bit of extra information attached (the person speaking). So something like this:

```
{"t":"Speech","speaker":"paul","c":[ ... ] }
```

**Problem #1**: At the point a lua-filter sees the document, it is obviously already distilled to an AST. This means replacing the items in a manner similar to what most macro expander samples do cannot really work since it would require reading forward. With this method, I just replace bits and pieces in place (<NAME| becomes a StartSpeech and the first solitary > that follows becomes an EndSpeech, but that would make malformed input a bigger potential problem because of silent-ish failures. Additionally, these tags would be completely out of sorts with how an AST is supposed to look.

To complicate matters even further, some of my characters end up learning a secondary language throughout the story, for which I apply a different format that contains a simplified understanding of the spoken text with perspective-characters understanding of what was said. Example:

```
<paul|"Heb je goed geslapen?"|"Did you ?????">
```

I could probably add a third 'UnderstoodSpeech' group to my filter, but (**problem #2**) at this point, the relationship between the speaker, the original speech, and the understood translation is completely gone. As long as the final documents need these values in these respective orders and only in these orders, it is fine... but what if I want my HTML version to look like

```
"Did you?????"
```

with a tool-tip / hover-over effect containing the original speech? That would be near impossible to achieve because the AST does not contain that kind of relational detail.

Whatever kind of AST I create in the filter is what I need to understand in my custom writer. Ideally, I want to re-use as much stock functionality of pandoc as possible for the writer, but I don't even know if that is feasible at this point.

So now my question: could someone with great pandoc understanding please give me an example on how to keep relevant data-bits together and apply them in the correct manner? By this I mean show a basic example of what needs to be put in the lua-filter and lua-writer scripts in the following toolchain

```
[CUSTOMIZED MARKDOWN INPUT] -> lua-filter -> lua-writer -> [CUSTOMIZED HTML5 OUTPUT]
```

Comment: Are you sure that Pandoc is the tool you really want to use for something this specific and complex?

Comment: @NicolBolas Why wouldn't I use it? At the core, my goal is still 'convert markdown document to something publishable', which is pretty much the entire business of pandoc. Reinventing all the other parts that it has already figured out how to do (and really well at that) is not going to be any easier, and for as far I can tell, the point of its universal AST representation and these scripting features is exactly to make it possible to tweak the output to be exacty what one needs.

Comment: "*At the core, my goal is still 'convert markdown document to something publishable',*" I disagree. Your goal is to create a different format, to invent new markup syntax to express a concept that Markdown *as a format* cannot express. You want to change Markdown itself. That's not the same as providing a different means of processing an AST. And I didn't say you needed to reinvent anything; there are other tools out there that are designed to allow you to invent syntax.

Comment: As long as using [pandoc markdown divs and spans](https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#divs-and-spans) (or other markdown constructs with attributes) suffices your syntax needs, pandoc is absolutely the right tool for the job.